# cannot run java program that executes weka commands

Tags: java, weka

I am trying to run a Java program that executes Weka commands. 
The program i am running is at http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code, under Incremental Classifiers, "A working example is  IncrementalClassifier.java."

This is my code, and I changed the address of the arff:

```
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesUpdateable;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * This example trains NaiveBayes incrementally on data obtained
 * from the ArffLoader.
 *
 * @author FracPete (fracpete at waikato dot ac dot nz)
 */
public class IncrementalClassifier {

  /**
   * Expects an ARFF file as first argument (class attribute is assumed
   * to be the last attribute).
   *
   * @param args        the commandline arguments
   * @throws Exception  if something goes wrong
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // load data
    ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
    loader.setFile(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Weka-3-6\\10random+5.arff"));
    Instances structure = loader.getStructure();
    structure.setClassIndex(structure.numAttributes() - 1);

    // train NaiveBayes
    NaiveBayesUpdateable nb = new NaiveBayesUpdateable();
    nb.buildClassifier(structure);
    Instance current;
    while ((current = loader.getNextInstance(structure)) != null)
      nb.updateClassifier(current);

    // output generated model
    System.out.println(nb);
  }
}
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \iris.2.arff (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at weka.classifiers.bayes.net.ADNode.main(ADNode.java:270)
```

How to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That file (iris.2.arff) seems to be hardcoded into the source, as shown [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Science/weka/weka/classifiers/bayes/net/ADNode.java.htm).  I would guess that this file came with the distribution but is not in the correct location.  Or possibly you are invoking the wrong method.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't know how to act on your feedback.

Comment: First, update your post to include the entire stack trace, and also indicate at which line in YOUR source the exception is thrown.

Comment: The errors that I get are: 1.Project 'CN170' is missing required library: 'C:\Program Files\Weka-3-4\weka.jar' (Resource: CN170, Location: Build path), 2. The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved (Resource: CN170, Location: unknown), 3. Unhandled exception type IOException (Resource: simpleprog.java, location: line18).

Comment: That's very different from the original error, and indicates that weka.jar is not in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you're running the wrong class in your java application configuration, what you have to do is :

right click on project : Run As : Run configuration : In the field "Main Class" choose your class "IncrementalClassifier"

that's all, good luck !